OAuth does not redirect user to Docker-hosted login page
I'm building a Blazor WASM app and I need to authenticate users via a 3rd party service (eventually, it will be Office 365). For testing purposes, I ran the Keycloak Docker image in which I created a realm BlazorTestRealm and a client blazor-client.
In my Program.cs in the Blazor project I added OIDC config:
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/BlazorTestRealm";
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "blazor-client";
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7245/auth-callback";
});

On the Login.razor page, under my classic user login form, I added a button for testing purposes which redirects to authentication/login:
    <MudButton @onclick="OAuth3rdPartyLogin">[ Login ]</MudButton>


private async Task OAuth3rdPartyLogin()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("authentication/login");
}

As I understand, the registered OIDC middleware service is supposed to handle the redirection to the authentication/login on the server running in Docker and the callback URI (from the RedirectUri config property) will redirect the browser back to my web app.
For some reason, the redirection to authentication/login does not work and instead the browser tries to open https://localhost:7245/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7245%2Fauthentication%2Flogin
What am I doing wrong?
